# How to get the UESRNAME and ID of the member who send the command?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

because i want to create the command anyone can use,i only want to get the UESRNAME and ID of the member who send the command and stored in variable(username,userid) .how can i do that?thanks

such like

```
    @bot.command()
    async def ping(ctx):
        await ctx.send(f'{round(bot.latency*1000)} ms')
```